# How to upgrade from siebel server 17 CRM to siebel 20?

Tags: siebel

I have copy of siebel server pack 17 CRM and instead of installing new one i want upgrade the existing server to server 20

Answer (score 0):

Siebel CRM Updates (such as 20.x) are released monthly by Oracle and apply on top of 17.0 or later. There is no need to upgrade. The Update Installer will recognize the environment, take a backup and copy over the new binaries.

Be aware that between 17.0 and today, Oracle has also added repository, schema and seed data changes. Depending on the update, there are different utilities that need to be executed after the binary update.

As of 20.3 and higher, the Update Installer for SES (Siebel Enterprise Server) includes the Post Install DB Update utility which runs automatically.

Make sure to check out the Release Notes and Bookshelf Guides.

See also https://www.siebelhub.com/main/2020/03/seamless-repository-delivery-framework.html

have a nice day

@lex